# protractor e2e test with angular library E/launcher - Error: ReferenceError: window is not defined

Tags: angular-cli, ng-packagr

I have developed some angular libraries with angular-cli 6.
Running the e2e the with protractor I have the following error:

```
E/launcher - Error: ReferenceError: window is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Projects\p1\node_modules\ngx-bootstrap\bundles\webpack:\ngx-bootstrap.umd\webpack\universalModuleDefinition:10:2)
    at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:587:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at C:\Users\ee44143\Projects\mifid2-ui-trunk\dist\sg-ng-core-components\bundles\sg-ng-core-components.umd.js:2:268
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Projects\p1\dist\sg-ng-core-components\bundles\sg-ng-core-components.umd.js:5:2)
Closing report
[11:47:28] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 100
An unexpected error occurred: undefined
```

It seems is due to something wrong in the library sg-ng-core-components that have the following dependences:

```
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.0-rc.0 || ^6.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.0-rc.0 || ^6.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.0-rc.0 || ^6.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.0-rc.0 || ^6.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.0-rc.0 || ^6.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.0-rc.0 || ^6.0.0",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^3.0.1",
    "rxjs": "^6.2.1",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.2.1"
  },
```

On google I could not found a solution.
Does anyone know how to solve this issue?